# Javascript Object within object using constructor approach

Tags: javascript

Am a newbie to JS really and am learning about Objects.

Basically I would like to know how to create nested objects using the constructor approach. My scenario is that I have Day constructor which has a name property, I also have an activities property.  I'd like the activities property to also be an object which has it's own properties.  How would I define this in the constructor?

Also with the constructor approach imagine I have an activity on a Monday but no activities on a Tuesday what is the correct way to state that I have no activities on the Tuesday object?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "constructor approach"?

Comment: I mean by defining an object using a constructor function:

function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the easiest way to do this is to probably not worry about classes and just create plain objects.

```
const days = [
  {
    name: 'monday',
    activities: [
      {
        name: 'Answer questions on stack overflow.'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'tuesday',
    activities: []
  }
]
```

But, since its part of the question, assuming the "constructor" approach means to use classes, you would simply create Day and Activity classes and essentially construct the same data structure.

The easiest way to do this is to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and transpile down to ES5 compatible code. So the es7, babel code, would look like this:

```
class Day {
  constructor(name, activities) {
    this.name = name
    this.activities = activities
  }
}
class Activity {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

const days = [
  new Day("monday", [new Activity("Answer questions on stack overflow.")])
  new Day("tuesday", [])
]
```

Writing classes in older javascript without the `class` syntax can get pretty complex but in this case it would be as simple as just declaring functions such as:

```
function Day(name, activities) {
  this.name = name;
  this.activities = activities;
}
function Activity(name) {
  this.name = name
}
var days = [
  new Day("monday", [new Activity("Answer questions on stack overflow.")])
  new Day("tuesday", [])
]
```